# How can I fix an unintended hole in my mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

[image: The mysterious hole]

I've created a hollow object with a Boolean Difference, but it has left a hole in the mesh that I can't seem to fix. There are no vertices on the periphery of the hole itself, and it extends across two faces at right angles to each other.

When I look inside the hollow (as far as I can), I see that there are "shadow" connections between vertices that I would have expected to be unrelated.

I've tried manually reducing the NGON faces to quads and triangles, but it's had no effect on the hole. I've tried Mesh > Cleanup > Fix Holes, also with no effect. I've tried to Beautify the affected faces, again with no effect.

I've attached a link to the file in a state prior to my messing around trying to fix it (approx. 10MB)

[Link to the .blend file, approx 10MB](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33836019/VickersLightMkII.blend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some [manifold Geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46809/2843) inside of your mesh. You can select the affected edges or vertices with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> in *Edit Mode*:

[image: Non-Manifold Edges]

You need to delete every connected Face and readd it manually in a "logical and watertight, clean" way.

After you corrected this - you need to delete this one face which isn't connected in one flat plane but with many of these vertices that got selected - you will get quite a clean tank model without holes ;-)

[image: Tank Model without holes]

Answer (score 2):

There is no hole in the mesh, but a non-planar n-gon (a polygon with more than 4 vertices) that is ovelapping on top another face.

You should delete it and try to reconnect the remaining geometry using quads...

[image]

Comment: Using `Ctrl`+`T` operator will triangulate Ngon which can be converted to quads after, this can allow skipping deleting face.