# Delete parts of a grid outside of another object

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, knife-tool

I created a grid (as multiple curve paths) which is in and outside of a sphere. When I'm trying to delete all parts outside with the Boolean Modifier, it says "Cannot execute boolean operation". How can I solve this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The Boolean modifier most likely will fail dealing with intersecting geometry, like one on intersections of the grid lines, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5140/cannot-execute-boolean-operation-when-subtracting-several-spheres-and-cylinder. It might be necessary to delete that intersecting geometry of grid before executing Boolean which can be quite cumbersome task.

Comment: I created a extra topic with this problem: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48159/fill-curve-cube-without-intersecting-parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you need a proper ([non-manifold](https://www.blender.org/manual/glossary/index.html#term-non-manifold)) mesh to do the Boolean operations with. The method you used to create your "Grid Cube" doesn't help here because it doesn't prouce one. You could check your mesh in *Edit Mode* hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> with the *Mesh Select Mode* set to *Edge* or *Vertex*.

Here's a better Method to create your Grid-Frame-Cube:

1. Create a small cube in the corner

   - Add a default Cube (2x2x2) in the Center and name it *miniCube*
   - Position your 3D Cursor to the front bottom left corner by selecting the Vertex in *Edit Mode* and use <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>, *Cursor to selected*
   - Pivot around the 3D Cursor and scale your Cube (<kbd>S</kbd>) by *0.25*.
2. Duplicate this small cube twice, name one *Grid* and one *inner*, then hide the original *miniCube* or move it to another Layer as a Backup. You might need it later again to play around with the following Bevel settings.
3. Select the *inner* Cube and in *Edit Mode* select every Vertex (<kbd>A</kbd>), then use an *Edge Bevel* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>) of *0.25*.
4. Select the *Grid* Cube and add a *Boolean Modifier* with the *inner* Cube as Object in *Difference* mode. (This will cut out the inner part, basically only leaving the grid-frame)
5. Add three Array Modifiers, one for each Axis to the *Grid* Cube. This basically creates the grid-frame-like Cube structure you created but with a proper geometry.

   - Set the *Count* to *4*
   - Set the *Relative Offset* to *0.0* on each but *1.0* for one axis: *x* for the first Modifier, *y* for the second and *z* for the third.
   - Check *Merge*

Now you can add the *Boolean Modifier* to the 2x2x2 Sphere in your Center with an *Intersect* Operation and the *Grid* as its Object and it will work fine:

[image: Sphere intersected with Grid Cube]

You could of course play with the Bevel of your small cube before to get your grid nicer looking. You could use more Segments or change the Profile from *0.5* which is "flat" to a smaller number like *0.25* to get a more rounded grid-frame. Its settings are available in the panel in the Toolbar once you confirm the Bevel before doing any other operation or by hitting <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46809/2843