# Fill Curve Cube without intersecting parts

Tags: mesh, objects, bezier-curves

I created a cube out with just Curve paths and filled it as shown at the screenshot. But this mode creates intersecting parts (Screenshot 3-4)
Is there a way to do this without intersecting parts?

[image]

[image: Settings]

[image]

[image]

[image: Intersections]

Comment: Don't forget to upvote if any of the answers helped you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a perfectly "flat" cube here's another method:

1. Duplicate the Default Cube (<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>), name it "inner".
2. With your *inner* Cube selected switch to *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>).
3. Inset your Faces:

   - With every Vertex selected (<kbd>A</kbd>) hit <kbd>I</kbd> for *Inset* and then hit <kbd>I</kbd> again to toggle *Individual* On.
   - Type *0.25* or how broad you want your outer Grid-Frame to be. Confirm with <kbd>LMB</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Invert your selection to select all corner Vertices. Maybe there's a bug, but it will only work properly after you perform and undo the inverse again. So press Selection > Inverse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>, Undo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> and Selection > Inverse again <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>.
5. Scale your corner Vertices accordingly to your previous Inset width. You need to substract the Inset width from *1.0*, so in this example Scale (<kbd>S</kbd>) by <kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> (*1.0* - *0.25* = *0.75*). The result will look a bit off while your Vertices are still selected, but once you deselect them, everything looks perfect.
6. Now hide the *inner* Cube after leaving Edit mode (<kbd>H</kbd>) so that it won't overlap with the next steps result.
7. Add a Boolean modifier in the *Modifiers* Properties Tab to your not yet changed Default Cube with a *Different* Operation and the *inner* Cube as Object et voilà:

[image: Flat Cube Frame]

Comment: When you want to have a clean edge structure on your result, you can first do a *Triangulate Faces* with Ctrl+T and then perform *Tris to Quads* with Alt+J and select a large *Max Shape Angle* there (F6).

Answer (score 3):

Well,This expected from what you did.There is no way to solve this.

Instead you can use the **Wireframe** modifier to generate a similar result.

[image: Wireframe]

You can also flatten the face to get a more neat result:

[image: Neat]

Flatting can be done using the keys <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>Axis</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> after selecting the right faces.

[image: Flatting]

Comment: How can this flattening be done?

Comment: @Samoth I Edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Duplicate the default Cube, name itself *Grid* and the other one *inner*.
2. Select the *inner* Cube and in *Edit Mode* select every Vertex (<kbd>A</kbd>), then use an *Edge Bevel* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>) of *0.25*, then hide it.
3. Select the *Grid* Cube and add a *Boolean Modifier* with the *inner* Cube as Object in *Difference* mode. (This will cut out the inner part)

[image: Example Result]

You could of course play with the Bevel of your *inner* cube before to get your grid nicer looking. You could use more Segments or change the Profile from 0.5 which is "flat" to a smaller number like 0.25 to get a more rounded grid-frame. Its settings are available in the panel in the Toolbar once you confirm the Bevel before doing any other operation or by hitting <kbd>F6</kbd>. Unfortunately there's a restriction to the Bevel Operation that you can't set the Profile to something lower than *0.15*. So you won't be able to produce a "flat structure* with it.